# IAP for IOS not asking me to purchase the item and gives me "no product"

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to implement IAP for my new version of my app in the app store.
here are everything I did :

1. made new version in itunes connect and the Status = Prepare for Upload.
2. add new products in "Manage in-app purchase"
3. create test user account.
4. implement the flowing code :

   ```
        -(IBAction)audio{
    //test the restriction
   if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){

   SKProductsRequest *skproductrequiste = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"AudioPlayer"]];
   skproductrequiste.delegate = self;
   [skproductrequiste start];
   }

   //after purshsing youcan show
    /*
   detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"show_pro"];
   detailViewController.product = @"audio";
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
   */

   }




    -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    SKProduct *validproducte = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];
    if (count >0) {
    validproducte = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    SKPayment *pay = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"AudioPlayer"];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addPayment:pay];
    }
    else{NSLog(@"no product");}
    }



   -(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
   for(SKPaymentTransaction *transiction in transactions){
       switch (transiction.transactionState) {
           case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
               break;

           case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
               NSLog(@"dobe buying");
               [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transiction];
               break;

           case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
               break;

           case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
               break;
       }
   }
   }
   ```

before I test my app in real device , I logged out of app store.then run the app and pressed the audio IBAction, but it gives me "no product". it did not even ask me to log in app store.
what is the problem here ? also , I am wondering how can I save customers purchasing in case if they deleted the app and reinstall again ?

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

1. IAP doesn't work on the simulator if you're trying it there.
2. A request for a list of products doesn't require a login.
3. Make sure your product ID is the EXACT same as what you entered in the Manage In App Purchase. It will return "0" if it doesn't match.
4. Sometimes the IAP "sandbox" is down and returns no items.  Check the IAP section of the Apple iOS developer forums to see if anybody else is seeing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your Contracts, Tax, and Banking information in your account. without that you will not get your product info.

Thank you

Comment: Your ProductIdentifiers is wrong

It must be like AZ7DXZQEDV.com.tmd.xyz

Comment: yes I know that, but change it here for security reason my actual ProductIdentifiers is like this : com.****.***.audioplayer